# Is the functor $\pi_{1}$ essentially surjective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

We know that for each topological space (say path connected), $\pi_{1}(X)$ is a group, the fundamental group of $X$. But if we take a group $G$, exists there a topological space X such that $\pi_{1}(X)=G$ ?

Comment: Yes:  $K(G,1)$'s or classifying spaces.

Comment: Yes. It's a standard construction. Pick a presentation of $G$, and for each generator, attach an independent circle to the base point. For each relation, glue a disc to the boundary formed by the word.

Comment: The question you ask is not what it means for $\pi_1$ to be a full functor!

Comment: More precisely, $\pi_1$ is a functor from the category of **pointed** topological spaces to the category of groups.

Comment: What you mean to ask is if $\pi_1$ is essentially surjective, which is true. A full functor is one which is a surjection on all the Hom sets, $\pi_1$ is not a full functor however.